# deployment of BWCE aplication on openshift using ansible tower getting failed

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, ansible, openshift

I am trying to deploy an BWCE application on OpenShift using ansible tower. But Ansible is not able to upgrade/install the application as it is not able to reach Kubernetes cluster.

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "command": "/usr/bin/helm list --output=yaml --filter workday-deploy", "msg": "Failure when executing Helm command. Exited 1.\nstdout: \nstderr: Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials\n", "stderr": "Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials

Below is the deployment yaml

```
---
- name: Deploy/Upgrade Puppetfiles Helm Chart
  hosts:
    -  localhost

  tasks:

  - name: Remove Existing Helm Chart Repository
    kubernetes.core.helm_repository:
      repo_state: "absent"
      name: "app-charts"
      
  - name: Add Helm Chart Repository
    kubernetes.core.helm_repository:
      name: "application"
      repo_url: "jfrog repo url"
      
  - name: Create Temporary Configuration Directory
    file:
      path: values/decrypted
      state: directory
      
  - name: Update Helm Repositories
    command: helm repo update 

      
  - name: Install/Upgrade workday-deploy Chart
    kubernetes.core.helm:
      validate_certs: no
      api_key: "{{ KUBERNETES_API_TOKEN }}"
      host: "clusterdetail"
      update_repo_cache: true
      release_name: "app-deploy"
      release_namespace: "tibco"
      chart_ref: "application"
      chart_version: "1.0.0"
      release_state: "present"
      create_namespace: yes
      atomic: yes
      values_files:
        - "values/decrypted/{{ HELM_VALUES_FILE }}"
```

Comment: **`the server has asked for the client to provide credentials`** highly suggests you did not provide any and that there's a problem in your environment configuration.